# Organic Groups Custom theme/layout

Tags: 7, organic-groups, theming

Hi I would like to give all organic group pages a custom theme and layout. How would I go about doing this? For example, I want the main site pages to follow a certain theme/layout, but when you go to any group page the theme and look is entirely different. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) module allows you, via the Context module to make duplicates of your theme settings for any context on your site. This gives you the ability for alternative layouts as a reaction in Context. The Delta module was originally created to compliment the powerful Omega base theme, but now works with ANY theme (3.x Version)

Answer (score 1):

I would like also to have different theme settings for each organic group(Different logo and different background colour).Could you please explain the steps how to do this with Context and Delta modules?
Actually what the path should be on the Context module so as to have different theme settings for each organic group?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Context doesn't let you set a Delta for Organic Groups. OG-Themes module is needed.